# LLDB equivalent of 'detach' in GDB in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, gdb, lldb

Is there any equivalent of GDB's 'detach' command in LLDB?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
process detach
```

I got this from [this list of lldb aliases](http://sealiesoftware.com/.lldb-gdb).

Comment: Thank you, @trojanfoe! One more useful table of GDB commands with the LLDB counterparts [http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html)